# The dimension of the space of solutions of $XY + YX = O$

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with different (not necessarily real) eigenvalues and real coefficients. Prove that the matrices N such that the $4 \times 4$

$M = \begin{pmatrix}A & N \\ 0 & A \end{pmatrix}$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ form a 2-dimensional subspace of the space of $2 \times 2$ real matrices.

Comment: The statement as it stands is false. $\pmatrix{A&N\\ 0&A}$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$ if and only if $\pmatrix{A&iN\\ 0&A}$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$. So, if you don't impose a further requirement that $N$ is real, the solution set for $N$ is never a nontrivial subspace of real matrices. By the way, it's not obvious how the your question title is related to the question body. Would you please either elaborate or edit the title?

Answer (score 0):

Call the block matrix in question $B$. Then $B$ diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$ if and only if $B-\frac12\operatorname{tr}(A)I_4$ is diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$. So, we may assume without loss of generality that $A$ is traceless. Let $p$ be the characteristic polynomial of this traceless $A$. Using the fact that $A$ has distinct complex eigenvalues, prove that $B$ is diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$ if and only if its minimal polynomial is equal to $p$. Hence show that in this case,
$$p(B)=\pmatrix{0&AN+NA\\ 0&0}.$$
Consequently you need to show that when $A$ is traceless and it has distinct complex eigenvalues, the set of all real matrices $N$ such that $AN+NA=0$ is a two-dimensional subspace of $M_2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: I think the justification for the use of $XY + YX =0$ in the title is contained in your conclusion.